# How to delete a MongoDB collection in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to check in PyMongo if collection exists and if exists empty (remove all from collection)?
I have tried like

```
collection.remove()
```

or

```
collection.remove({})
```

but it doesn't delete collection. How to do that ?

Answer (score 72):

Sample code in Pymongo with comment as explanation:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017) #Connect to mongodb

print(connection.database_names())  #Return a list of db, equal to: > show dbs

db = connection['testdb1']          #equal to: > use testdb1
print(db.list_collection_names())        #Return a list of collections in 'testdb1'
print("posts" in db.list_collection_names())     #Check if collection "posts" 
                                            #  exists in db (testdb1)

collection = db['posts']
print(collection.count() == 0)    #Check if collection named 'posts' is empty

collection.drop()                 #Delete(drop) collection named 'posts' from db and all documents contained.
```

Comment: do you really want to be querying all collections in the database every time you want to check if the collection exists?

Comment: @MoatazElmasry, method for checking if collection exists has not yet been implemented in mongodb, you can check on this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1938

Comment: @MoatazElmasry meanwhile, if you really need to optimize the performance of you application, you can resort to other techniques such as pre-caching collection results.

Answer (score 21):

You should use `.drop()` instead of `.remove()`, see documentation for detail: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.drop

=====

Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

To check if a collection exists, use method `collection_names` on database:

```
>>> collection_name in database.list_collection_names()
```

To check if a collection is empty, use:

```
>>> collection.count() == 0
```

both will return True or False in result.

Comment: `collection_names` is deprecated. Use `list_collection_names` instead

Comment: this works. it's scary this will drop everything without asking for confirmation...

Comment: @citynorman Well, it's an API not CLI, assuming you understand what you are doing, same in other DSLs like MySQL's `DROP TABLE`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this:

`db.collection.remove();`

Comment: db.collection.remove() only removes all records from collection that matches the query given in remove. Eg db.collection.remove({name: 'abc'}) will remove all records with name 'abc', empty query in remove will cause all records to be removed, but collection will stay as it is.