# Determine whether collection in MongoDB exists in Python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I want to know whether collections of specific names exists in the MongoDB. How can I achieve this programmatically in Python. On searching about the same, I got to know how to do that from MongoDB shell but nothing useful for doing the same in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in PyMongo if collection exists and if exists empty (remove all from collection)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822575/how-to-check-in-pymongo-if-collection-exists-and-if-exists-empty-remove-all-fro)

Comment: @Alex : Thanks ... that solved my problem :)

Comment: @Alex : Can you please post this as answer so that I can accept this as final answer?

Answer (score 16):

You can use the method to retrieve and check if your collection exists or not from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826294/10183880) given by the @Alex like this:

**Method 1:**

```
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)  # Connect to mongodb

db = connection['test_db']
list_of_collections = db.list_collection_names()  # Return a list of collections in 'test_db'
print("posts" in list_of_collections)  # Check if collection "posts" exists in db (test_db)
```

Or, you can validate a collection with `validate_collection()` ([documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=list_collection_names#pymongo.database.Database.validate_collection)) This returns an error (`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure`) if the collection doesn't exist. **With this method, you can also catch that exception and do whatever you want.**

**Method 2:**

```
import pymongo
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)  # Connect to mongodb

db = connection['test_db']

try:
    db.validate_collection("random_collection_name")  # Try to validate a collection
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:  # If the collection doesn't exist
    print("This collection doesn't exist")
```

Comment: I really prefer the second Method, especially since it also allows you to see if a collection is actually a collection or a view, since list_collection_names() also returns views.

Comment: if you're getting `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: user is not allowed to do action [validate]` change role to `Admin`

Comment: Doesn't work as expected...  The OperationFailure exception does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete approach testing connection, database and collection.

**Thanks!**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import PyMongoError


def connect_to_mongodb(conn_str: str, database: str, collection: str):
    """Opens the connection to MongoDB."""

    try:
        mongo_client: MongoClient = MongoClient(conn_str)

        # NOTE: The ismaster command is cheap and does not require auth. Useful to
        # test if the connection is valid.
        mongo_client.admin.command("ismaster")

        # NOTE: Test if the base date is valid.
        if database not in mongo_client.list_database_names():
            raise PyMongoError("Invalid data base!")

        # NOTE: Test if the collection is valid.
        if collection not in mongo_client[database].list_collection_names():
            raise PyMongoError("Invalid collection!")

    except PyMongoError as e:
        print("Connection to MongoDB failed. Cause: %s" % (e))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://your_mongo_connection_string')
db = client['your_database_name']
collection = db['collectionName']  

if collection.count_documents({}):
    *#your code based on fondition*
```

this will check if there is collection exist