# How to create collection with index if not exists in pymongo?

Tags: python, indexing, pymongo

I was using automatic collection creation in pymongo:

```
client = MongoClient(url)
db = client.get_default_database()
my_collection = db['my_collection']
```

I was thinking it created automatically on last statement and added

```
index_name = 'my_index'
if index_name not in my_collection.index_information():
     my_collection.create_index(..., name=index_name, unique=False)
```

Unfortunately, this led to error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Collection ... doesn't exist
```

This made me think, that collection is created on first save. This gives me no place to put index creation code.

So, the question is: how to create collection with index, but only if it doesn't exist?

I have read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826294/258483 but don't like how it implies to write check of existence twice:

```
client = MongoClient(url)
db = client.get_default_database()
if 'my_collection' not in db.collection_names():
    db.createCollection('my_collection')

my_collection = db['my_collection']
index_name = 'my_index'
if index_name not in my_collection.index_information():
     my_collection.create_index(..., name=index_name, unique=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

As you see, calling `index_information` on a collection that doesn't exist yet throws OperationFailure.

Just call `create_index` without checking first:

```
client = MongoClient(url)
db = client.get_default_database()
my_collection = db['my_collection']
index_name = 'my_index'
my_collection.create_index(..., name=index_name, unique=False)
```

If the index already exists, the MongoDB server ignores the command. If the index does not exist, MongoDB creates the collection (if necessary) and the index on the collection.

Comment: This will raise `OperationFailure` won't it?

Comment: If the index already exists, the MongoDB server ignores the command.

Comment: the case is that collection can be non-existing

Comment: Try it out and see! You can create an index on a non-existent collection and MongoDB automatically creates the collection.